# Single controller to handle resolves in two routes, collection and single in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, mvw

This might be a common problem that a angularjs dev will encounter, and I don't know if this was already been answered in the past, a brief searching doesn't give me results.

Okay, I have 2 related routes, likes so:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('user', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'views/sometemplate.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'
  })
  .state('user.collection', {
     url: '/user',
     resolve: {
       users: function(User) {
          return User.query()
       }
     },
  })
  .state('user.detail', {
     url: '/user/:id',
     resolve: {
       user: function($stateParams, User) {
          return User.get({id: $stateParams.id})
       }
     },
  });
```

The problem with this is that if I access the route `/user`, the controller requires two 2 provider, users and user.

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, user, users) {
  $scope.user = user;
  $scope.users = users;
 })
```

Do you recommend having 2 separate controllers for this, if yes, how do you usually name your controllers, but I don't think its nice to have 2 different controllers, since it is not totally different, same domain still.